# Discrete Mathematics (Statement)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

1) x^2 + x + 1 = 0 , x is a real number.

Answer: Is a statement.

2) x^2 + x + 1 = 0 , x is complex number.

Answer: Is not a statement.

Why the question no.2 is not a statment ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/ - try this site

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on Jiale's answer:

A statement is a statement which has a definite truth value.

> 1) x^2 + x + 1 = 0 , x is a real number.

This can be considered a statement because it is always false regardless of how x is chosen. This is because there is no real number which satisfies this equation. Therefore, it is guaranteed to have a definite truth value: false.

> 2) x^2 + x + 1 = 0 , x is complex number.

This cannot be considered a statement because it is true for some complex numbers x, and false for others. The truth value of this expression is only definite once x is specified. Therefore, it is not a statement.

Answer (score 0):

Reason: A Statement is a declarative statement that is either true or false but not both.

Comment: But not both. Then the answer for question no.1 should also be not a statement. Am I right ?

Comment: That can be considered as a statement because it is always false regardless of how x is chosen. This is because there is no real number which satisfies this equation. Therefore, it is guaranteed to have a definite truth value: false.